# NightwatchJS iterating links with browser.back()

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, iteration, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to iterate over the links and upon each click assert the page exists and return back. So far I've got to this function in the test case. The problem is that after clicking the first link and navigating back browser navigates back one more time and then the iteration is done on the empty page. If I switch back() with init() the test still fails. 
This is the test case, not a page object command. Please help

ChromeDriver **v.2.28.455517** 
Selenium **v2.53.0**

```
browser.elements('css selector', 'specific element', function(allLinks) {
        allLinks.value.forEach(function(index) {
            console.log('Element value is ' + index.ELEMENT)
            browser.elementIdClick(index.ELEMENT, function(res) {
                this.waitForElementVisible('body', 2000);
                this.back();
                this.pause(1000);
            });
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made it working with the following(snippet below in case one will struggle with this). Though I don't really like this solution because it is very unstable. If someone has a better **working** example, please share it and kudos to you will be guaranteed!

```
'links': function(browser) {
        browser.elements('css selector', '#footer .footerlist .links li a', function(res) { 
            for (let i = 1; i < res.value.length; i++) {
                browser.click('#footer .footerlist .links li:nth-child(' + i + ') a');
                browser.pause(2000);
                browser.waitForElementVisible('body', 1000);
                browser.url('');
            } 
        })
    }
```